Change integration order $\int_{-2}^2\mathrm dx\int_{-2+\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{2+\sqrt{4-x^2}}f(x,y)\mathrm dy$
How do I change the order of this integral?
$$\int_{-2}^2\mathrm dx\int_{-2+\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{2+\sqrt{4-x^2}}f(x,y)\mathrm dy$$
I tried to plot a graph of this function and got two semicircles with radiuses R = 2 and centers (-2;0) and (2;0). There are also straight lines x = -2 and x = 2. It is not clear in what order to write this integral

break it into four integrals, 1: the upper semicircle  2:  the middle rectangle 3: the funny piece with x > 0 and y < 0  4:  the funny piece with x < 0 and y < 0

@WillJagy: thank you, i just forget about the middle rectangle
